# C code Float to Int (format print string) convert decimals

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to write a format print string that outputs this number (`float 0.2005`) as a percent with only 2 decimals (`20.05%`).

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 3):

Use `%%` to output the `%` sign itself, and use `.2` to control precision.

```
float f = 0.2005;
printf("%.2f%%\n", f * 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Spontaneously, I would do this:

```
float a = 0.2005;
printf("%.2f%%\n", a * 100.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
main()
{
    float a = 0.2005;
    float b = a * 100;
    printf("%.2f\n",b);
}
```